# How to create just like array in SQL Server 2005/2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I know we can not create array in SQL Server. There are 25 different tables in my database. I want to add extra column to those tables. So I wanted to have an array so I can store my table name into. One by one I can access them and insert new column. In SQL Server there is no for loop, I can use while loop.

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays -- just tables.  Conceptually, a table is an array.

Comment: why can you not simply just write the ALTER TABLE script for each table? Will take you longer to figure out the correct WHILE LOOP than it will to create 25 quick ALTER TABLE lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store your table names into a **table variable** and then also have a `Done` column in that table variable - something like:

```
DECLARE @AllMyTables TABLE (TableName VARCHAR(200), Done BIT)
```

and then insert your tables into that table variable:

```
INSERT INTO @AllMyTables(TableName, Done)
    SELECT name, 0
    FROM sys.tables
```

Now, you can easily fetch one table at a time and do something with it:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(200)

SELECT TOP (1) @TableName = TableName FROM @AllMyTables WHERE Done = 0
```

and now add your column, update the `Done` column to indicate you're done, and on you go....